# Using Select Layer By Attribute in ArcGIS ModelBuilder multiple times?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute

I want to use *Select Layer By Attribute* in ArcGIS ModelBuilder multiple times. 
It works everything fine until a new feature is created (e.g. after *Dissolve* or *Multipart to Singlepart*). Then I can't apply *Select Layer By Attribute* anymore. The *Layer Name or Table View* of the Dissolved feature is not selectabled in the *Select Layer By Attribute* menu. My workaround at the moment is to build many little models.

Question: How can I use *Select Layer By Attribute* in ModelBuilder after a new feature is created?

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that it goes wrong when your model becomes white?! After you've used *Dissolve*, won't the output be a feature class and thereby not a layer. In modelbuilder *Select Layer By Attribute* only works with layers. Put in a *Make Feature Layer* tool after the *Dissolve* to start a new selection.